# javascript - position functions returns 0

Tags: javascript

Icefaces has a method for positioning a popup WHERE you click the **mouse**. I disabled the portion of the code where the coordinates of the mouse click are taken because I want to put this menuPopup at the position where my targComp (which is actually a div) is located (so fixed location iso mouse location).

The javascript method called is:

```
function contextMenuPopup(event, popupMenu, targComp) {
var dynamic = $(popupMenu + "_dynamic");
if (!event) {
    event = window.event;
}
if (event) {
    event.returnValue = false;
    event.cancelBubble = true;

    if (event.stopPropagation) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }

    var posx = 0; // Mouse position relative to
    var posy = 0; // the document
    /*
     * if (event.pageX || event.pageY) { posx = event.pageX; posy =
     * event.pageY; } else if (event.clientX || event.clientY) { posx =
     * event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft +
     * document.documentElement.scrollLeft; posy = event.clientY +
     * document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop; }
     */
    alert(Left(targComp));
    Ice.Menu.showIt(posX, posY, popupMenu, targComp);
}
}
```

You see that I only commented old code and add an alert to find out if my methods which return the position of the targComp are correctly calculating the value.

```
function Left( el ) {
var _x = 0;
while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
    _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
    el = el.parentNode;
}
return _x;
}

function Top( el ) {
    var _y = 0;
    while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
        _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
        el = el.parentNode;
    }
    return _y;
}
```

I do not understand why **my alert return 0** when I surely know that my targComp div is not at that left coordinate...

Do you see any problem? (yeah, I know I have to replace the posX and posY at the showIt method, but I'll do that after I am sure that Left and Top are correct (which by the way are copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/dynamically-retrieve-html-element-x-y-position-with-javascript) so already confirmed that these methods are working fine...)

Then where it's the problem?

Html code:

```
<div class="icePnlGrp graMainMenuTabDefault" id="frmMainMenu:divMenuPopupAP" onmouseover="contextMenuPopup(event, 'frmMainMenu:menuPopupAP_sub', 'frmMainMenu:divMenuPopupAPSmall');return false;">
    <label class="iceOutLbl graMainMenuTabText" id="frmMainMenu:j_id54">Application Portfolio</label>
    <div class="icePnlGrp" id="frmMainMenu:divMenuPopupAPSmall" style="border-style:solid; border-width:1px;">
</div>
</div>
```

**Update** (after solving the above problem): I attach a screenshot wondering why the mouse position is calculated correctly when I press click inside that targetComp div but the position of the div is wrong...?

[image]

**Update solved:** seems that I do need *targCompObject.offsetLeft, targCompObject.offsetTop,*
instead of calliny those Top and Left functions.

where

```
targCompObject = document.getElementById(targComp);
```

So the final call is:

```
Ice.Menu.showIt(targCompObject.offsetLeft, targCompObject.offsetTop,
            popupMenu, targComp);
```

Comment: you sure `targComp` is a valid reference to your div? Likely that you're not passing in a valid DOM element for that parameter

Comment: Just added the html code to prove that...

Comment: @Christian What is `frmMainMenu:menuPopupAP_sub` relative to `frmMainMenu:divMenuPopupAP`? I don't think that you need to hard-code those ID values into the onmouseover attribute.

Comment: @Sime That is that id of the menuPopup which I show when hover on the div...

Comment: @Cristian But what is their relation? Ancestor/descendant? Siblings?

Comment: @Sime It's a descendant of the div which has all the menu.

Comment: @Cristian That's what I thought. I recommend you to not hard-code the ID names into the onmouseover attribute, but rather select the associated elements via JavaScript from within the handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in the **id** of the target element, not the element itself.

Somewhere in the popup handler you need

```
targComp = document.getElementById(targComp);
```

You could make it check first to see whether it's a string, so that you could optionally call it with a DOM element reference too.

Comment: OK well you write that it's solved now - so everything is ok?